# How to obtain the underlying SQL types for query results in .NET/C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, sql-types

For example, the following code prints "`System.Int32`", not "`int`":

```csharp
string connArgs = "..."; // use your settings here
string query = "SELECT 1";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connArgs)) {
  conn.Open();
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
  using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    for (int col = 0; col < reader.VisibleFieldCount; ++col)
      Console.WriteLine(reader.GetFieldType(col));
}
```

How can I obtain *the underlying SQL type*, not just its equivalent .NET system type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`GetDataTypeName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatatypename.aspx) method for that:

> Gets a string representing the data type of the specified column.

```
for (int col = 0; col < reader.VisibleFieldCount; ++col) {
    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetDataTypeName(col));
}
```